How to upload Artifact in GitHub Workflow from Ubuntu 18.04 container now V4 is deprecated?
I run a GitHub Actions workflow compiling my program for some legacy system using Petalinux 2019.1. To do so, I have a Docker container based on Ubuntu 18.04 (latest supported Ubuntu version for Petalinux 2019.1).  The build result package is uploaded using the GitHub Upload Artifact V3 action. However, this actions is now deprecated.
I cannot update to Upload Artifact V4, because that version doesn't support Ubuntu 18.04. (NodeJS 20 will throw the following error:

/__e/node20/bin/node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /__e/node20/bin/node)

Here is a minimal working example for my workflow file:
name: Build old project
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'test/**'

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  host:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: ubuntu:18.04
    env:
      ACTIONS_ALLOW_USE_UNSECURE_NODE_VERSION: true 
    steps:
      - name: Build
        run: echo "Building stuff with petalinux:2019.1" > result.txt
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: legacy_build
          path: result.txt

What would be the best way to upload my artifacts without having to update my Petalinux version?
Addition remarks:

It would be nice to do the upload-artifact step outside of the container while doing the build step inside the container, but apparently you can only define a container for the whole job.
ACTIONS_ALLOW_USE_UNSECURE_NODE_VERSION is used to keep the workflow working for now.
Updating my Petalinux version is not an option, as this is a legacy system that we will only support for a few more years.


One way can be to compile your own version of glibc and patch node to use it - https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/1392#issuecomment-1815887430

@brc-dd this solution seems to work for running NodeJS 20 inside the container, but the GitHub Runner will still use the package provided by GitHub itself, located at /__e/node20/bin/node.

Can /__e/node20/bin/node be patched, @Fiero?

@EdSabol, no, that is a read only disk managed by GitHub.

You would have to use actions/toolkit via javascript
